# Entity Object attached/not attached to dbContext

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

I have the following EF data statement :

```
class Model1{
    public Int32  Id{ get; set; }
    public string Prop1 { get; set; }
    public string Prop2 { get; set; }
    public string Prop3 { get; set; }
    public virtual Model3 PropModel31{ get; set; }
    public virtual Model3 PropModel32{ get; set; }
}
class Model3{
    public Int32  Id{ get; set; }
    public string Prop1 { get; set; }
    public string Prop2 { get; set; }
}
```

I request my entities in different places :

```
//db being the datacontext
//Partial view of Model1
var model1s = from model1 in db.Model1
    select new {
                 model1.Id,
                 model1.Prop1,
                 model1.Prop2,
                 model1.PropModel31,
                 model1.PropModel32,
    };
```

And, later, I am trying to update a model entity,

```
public ActionResult Save(Model1 model1)
{
    db.Model1.Attach(model1);
    var entry = db.Entry(model1);
    entry.Property(e => e.Prop1).IsModified = true;
    entry.Property(e => e.Prop2).IsModified = true;
    ...
    db.SaveChanges();
}
```

but I get the following exception :

*An object with the same key already exists in the ObjectStateManager. The ObjectStateManager cannot track multiple objects with the same key.*

If I comment **db.Model1.Attach(model1);** then I get the opposite exception :/

*Member 'IsModified' cannot be called for property 'Prop1' because the entity of type 'Model1' does not exist in the context. To add an entity to the context call the Add or Attach method of DbSet*

So, my guess is that the Model3 entity properties are attached to the context, but how can check that, fix it?

Thank you for your help.

Comment: so why exactly are you disabling change tracking and then expecting the context to track the changes anyway?

Comment: Sorry, Not sure about your question? Let's say I do not want any tracking, how can I save my entity in the db?

Comment: that's the point of tracking, so that the context knows what's been changed in the model compared to the database.  using AsNoTracking basically causes a lookup that the context isn't tracking, so when you change the entity and then try to save, you have a conflict like you are adding a new entry in conflict with an existing database item.

Comment: also, you have Lazy Loaded Navigation properties, which are going to be tracked the moment they are accessed, since Lazy Loading defers the lookup.  Perhaps what you want to do will work if you use `.Include()` on your Navigation properties to force them to load in the same call

Comment: Ok, thanks for the details. I removed the AsNoTracking(), still having the same issue. I'll edit my question to match the changes

Comment: without AsNoTracking() you shouldn't need to attach the model

Comment: Well, then I get the other exception. Sorry, I am confused with this tracking system :/

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/45967/discussion-between-andrew-counts-and-yoann)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, the exception is triggered because one of the sub entity property **PropModel31** was reset to new (with Id=0).

The exception was not really explicit.

Thanks a million to Andrew Counts for his time and expertise!

Answer (score 0):

You need a new instance of your DbContext:

```
public ActionResult Save(Model1 model1)
{
    using (var ctx = new MyDbContext())
    {
        ctx.Model1.Attach(model1);
        var entry = ctx.Entry(model1);
        entry.Property(e => e.Prop1).IsModified = true;
        entry.Property(e => e.Prop2).IsModified = true;
        ...
        ctx.SaveChanges();
    }
}
```

Comment: Same problem unfortunately.